# GA Custom Dimensions in Wordpress - implement datalayers correctly

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I need some guidance on a problem I can't solve with google so far.

Situation:
I have a wordpress site with the custom post type Jobs. With the plugin Advanced Custom Fields I created custom fields i want to track (location, type of contract, company).

In google Analytics I created 5 custom Dimensions:

1. postCategories (can be Blog or Job category and can have more than 1)
2. postTags (same as 1)
3. jobContract
4. jobLocation
5. jobCompany

My Question: how do I pull the variables from WordPress? I know that i can do this with GTM and Datalayers, but i don't know what code i have to implement into my wordpress site to push these variables into Datalayers so that GA can track it as Custom Dimensions. I also struggle with the multiple category thing. If i define data layers, how can i track multiple Categories for 1 pageview?

I hope my description is clear, if not feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have set up your pageview tag in GTM, you can add the variables from the JavaScript macros within the “custom dimension” field under the tag set up.

Go to variables and create a custom variable and to retrieve these tags. Depending on how they are displayed would change how you can retrieve them.

Can you post a screen shot of what the page looks like or a URL to view?